# setUp before all classes when phpunit command runs on folder

Tags: php, selenium, automation, phpunit

I am working with PHP-Selenium and created many clases in my scripts directory.

Now when i run "phpunit scripts", it runs all the test case in that directory.

But as I want to delete all screen shots from particular folder when i have run "phpunit scripts".

What is prefer way to do this ? I tried setUp and setUpBeforeClass, but these does not suit the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If your `setUp` and `setUpBeforeClass`'s aren't working, try just creating a quick bash file to accomplish your task.

start

```
#!/bin/sh
# first lets clear the screenshot dir.
print "clearing screenshots..."
rm -fr ./screenshots
print "done."

# now lets start the unit tests.
print "starting unit tests..."
phpunit scripts
print "done."
```

Now run the file:

```
$ ./start
clearing screenshots...
done.
starting unit tests...
(tests run)
done.
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Listener that will delete the folder before the "scripts" suite starts.

```
class ScreenshotsPurgeListener implements \PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener
{
    public function startTestSuite(\PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite) {
    if ("scripts" == $suite->getName()) {
            // delete screenshots
        }           
    }

    public function addError(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, \Exception $e, $time) {}
    public function addFailure(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, \PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e, $time) {} 
    public function startTest(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test) { }
    public function endTest(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $time) { }
    public function addIncompleteTest(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, \Exception $e, $time) { }
    public function addSkippedTest(\PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, \Exception $e, $time) { }
    public function endTestSuite(\PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite) {}
}
```

As explained in the [PHPUnit docs](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener).

You must activate the listener at phpunit.xml file:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class="ScreenshotsPurgeListener" file="listeners/screenshots/ScreenshotsPurgeListener.php"/>
</listeners>
```